# Xamarin.Forms using Resources x:Key not available

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application (By the way, I am new to Xamarin).  I have quite a few  elements on the page.  I want to set the color of the button based on a property value in my view model.  I have a custom IValueConverter class to convert an integer value to a different color object based on the integer value.

I am not quite sure on how to get this working. I am using Brian Lagunas' prism nuget packages and templates. Here is my sample code as image.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
         x:Class="PlayAlongJ.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PlayAlongJ.Converters;assembly=PlayAlongJ"
         Title="Play-along with J">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:IntToColorConverter x:Name="intToColor"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="15,30">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Chest Total" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button x:Name="ChestTotal" Text="{Binding ChestAmount}" 
                      BackgroundColor="Blue"
                      TextColor="White" WidthRequest="150"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The first Problem I am facing is that in my page resource dictionary section, I can't get x:Key property for any resource I am trying to use. I only get a x:Name property.  For example, if I want to set a Style resource with  syntax and I only get x:Name, not x:Key.  I am also trying to use my value converter.  When I use it as , again I only get x:Name, not x:Key.  If I choose to use x:Name in the dictionary resource, I get a compilation error saying that resource requires a x:Key, which obviously I can't use since it is not available to me.

Here is my IValueConverter Implementation.  Can someone please show me how to setup the resources and my converter properly?  I prefer setting them up in XAML rather than in code.  Also, once I can setup the resources without compilation errors, a sample line of code to setup the BackgroundColor of my button to a bound integer property in my viewmodel.  If the integer is negative, I want to use Red, otherwise, use some other color using the value converter.

```
public class IntToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToInt32(value) >= 0 ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `x:Key` attribute like the error message is telling you. This is one of those cases where IntelliSense in XAML files fails to show every possible option that there is. If it doesn't show up, doesn't mean it's not available when you are working with XAML.

Take a look at [the Xamarin documentation on Resource Dictionaries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries/#Creating_and_Consuming_a_ResourceDictionary) for a full explanation on how to use the `x:Key` attribute on your resources. The most important part in that article regarding your question is:

> Each resource have a key that is specified using the x:Key attribute, which gives it a descriptive key in the ResourceDictionary.

You would then use your converter through the `StaticResource` markup extension like this (look at the content of the `BackgroundColor` property):

```xml
 <Button x:Name="ChestTotal" Text="{Binding ChestAmount}" 
     BackgroundColor="{Binding ChestAmount, Converter={StaticResource intToColor}}"
     TextColor="White" WidthRequest="150"></Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what it is telling you, you should use `x:Key`, like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <converters:IntToColorConverter x:Key="intToColor"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The IntelliSense can fail at these things sometimes. TO make sure your XAML is in order, you could have a look at [XAML Compilation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/).

It should then be available as a `StaticResource` and you can use it in your button like this:

```
<Button x:Name="ChestTotal" Text="{Binding ChestAmount}" BackgroundColor="{Binding ChestAmount, Converter={StaticResource intToColor}}" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="150"></Button>
```

Also follow [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#Bindings_and_Collections) to the Xamarin documentation for a bit more extensive explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I have marked Tim's answer as accepted only because his answer came first.  But thanks all the same.

Comment: Ah, totally overlooked that one, that is the right thing to do! Glad it helped!